# Please help me to read ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata

Tags: mysql, innodb, logfiles

Currently I am trying to get the lost records that have been deleted from mysql database.

I have viewed the entries in logfile1 and logfile0 it seems to be correct.

Any viewer or conversion that can help to create a txt file or be able to read the files will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have binary logging enabled, look in the mysql data directory for file names starting with `mysql-bin.0000*`

Then, after locating the transactions you nee, you can do something like the following to replay them:

```
mysqlbinlog binlog | mysql -u root -p
```

See [the official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html) on mysqlbinlog.

Also, [this blog](http://linuxrnd.blogspot.com/2011/12/mysql-recover-data-using-ibdata1.html) has a post on using just the logfiles you mentioned to do a restore (be sure to backup everything before doing this and make sure to test on a copy), after which you could select the data you want from the copy to the original.